# Finding $\lim \limits_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int _{\Gamma_R} \frac1{(z+i)^2 (z-i)^2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Gamma_R $ be the half circle centred at $0$ and radius $R>3$ with $Im(z) \geq 0$. Show that $$\lim  \limits_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int _{\Gamma_R} \frac1{(z+i)^2 (z-i)^2}dz=0$$

Is this region even closed? And I was thinking of using the $ML$ lemma but wouldn't that show it is zero for the modulus of the integral?

Please help. The denominator was originally $(z^2 +1)^2$ but i changed it just incase we might have to use Residue theorem. Would showing $$ \Bigg|\int _{\Gamma_R} \frac1{(z+i)^2 (z-i)^2} \Bigg| \leq ML$$ and then showing $ML \rightarrow 0$ answer the question?

Comment: i'm not sure if $\Gamma$ denotes the half circle without the real line or is it included? The proposition only makes sense if not. Otherwise the value would be $\pi/2$.

Comment: I wrote it word for word. So should we assume that it is a semi circle with a horizontal line in the real line from -R to R?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{|(z+i)^2(z-i)^2|} \le \frac{1}{(R-1)^4}$ on $\Gamma_R$.

Comment: It cannot be a semicircle with a horizontal line. Otherwise, the limit of the integral won't be zero.

Comment: @achillehui Can we do, since $|z|=R$ then since $$\frac1{ \big|(z^2 +1)^2 \big|} =\frac1{|z^2+1|^2} \leq \frac1{ (|z|^2 -1)^2} < \frac1{|z|^2-1}=\frac1{R^2 -1}=M$$ and $L=\pi R$. By the $ML$ lemma, $$\Bigg| \int _{\Gamma_R} f(z)dz \Bigg| \leq ML$$ and since $ML \rightarrow 0$ and $R \rightarrow \infty$, this gives us the answer to the original question????

Comment: @cooldudeman Yes you can, since $R^2 - 1 > 1 $, all your inequalities are valid.

Comment: @achillehui So if we prove that the modulus of it tends to zero, then the non modulus of it also tends to zero? (I think that this is obvious but im just being stupid)

Comment: @cooldudeman yes. In general, $| \int f(z) dz | \le \int | f(z) | |dz| $, if you can show the RHS tends to $0$ when you adjust some parameter, the LHS also tends to $0$. (this is one variant of the squeezing lemma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left|\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{dz}{(z^2+1)^2}\right|\le\frac{\pi R}{R^4-1}\xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{}0$$